# Access custom functions from embedded ruby

Tags: ruby, embedded-ruby

I have some Ruby/ERB code I am modifying

ERB:

```
"<%= register.endbit(address) %>"
```

Ruby:

```
def endbit(addr=nil,limit_to_max=false)
     if addr.nil?
        b = self.startbit + self.width - 1
     else
        b = addr.bits_in_register(self.name).last.reg_position
     end
     limit_to_max && !self.max_width.nil? && b >= self.max_width ? self.max_width - 1 : b         
  end
```

This is the code that came with and works fine.

I added my own function to the ruby file called return_a

```
def return_in(input)
   return input
end
```

in the ERB file, I have only this line:

```
"<%= register.return_in("a") %>"
```

I get an error

```
FAILED 1 error: undefined method `return_in' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In this case it seems that you aren't facing a problem with the `return_in` method itself, but your variable `@register` seems to be `nil`, can you post where/how this variable is set?

Comment: in the original erb you had <%= register.endbit ... %> in the new file you have <% @register ... i think one of those is a typo, which one?

Comment: BTW, Bike is the best of the three :) Swim is fine, Run is pain, Bike is just plain fun

Comment: Oh right `@register' is wrong, it should be `register'. The big problem turned out to be the file I was putting the return_in function in was read only! Working now